# Is the bra-ket scalar product the only function invariant under unitary transformations?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space

In Sabine's recent paper on a proof of Born's rule, she asserts that transition probabilities must be functions of the scalar product of the initial and final states.

> **Section 2** Proof
> Since $P_N$ is invariant under unitary operations, transition probabilities
> can only be functions of scalar products

How does one prove this statement?

[image]

[1] S. Hossenfelder, "A derivation of Born’s rule from symmetry", [*Annals Phys.* **425** (2021) 168394](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.aop.2020.168394), [arXiv:2006.14175](https://arxiv.org/abs/2006.14175).

Comment: Please [do not post images of texts you want to quote](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10563), but type it out instead so it is readable for all users and so that it can be indexed by search engines. For formulae, use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020) instead.

Comment: https://pubpeer.com/publications/6B15E8CEF3372A4EFDA0743861B63C

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $|\psi_1  \rangle, |\phi_1 \rangle,|\psi_2 \rangle,| \phi_2 \rangle$ be unit vectors such that :
$$ \langle \psi_1 |\phi_1 \rangle = \langle \psi_2 |\phi_2 \rangle$$

Then, there is a unitary map $U$ such that :
$$U |\psi_1 \rangle = |\psi_2 \rangle $$
and
$$U |\phi_1 \rangle = |\phi_2 \rangle $$

Since, $P_N$ is invariant under unitary transformations, we have :
$$P_N( |\psi_1  \rangle \to |\phi_1 \rangle) = P_N(|\psi_2 \rangle \to | \phi_2 \rangle)$$

This means that $P_N( |\psi_1  \rangle \to |\phi_1 \rangle)$ only depends on $\langle \psi_1 |\phi_1 \rangle$ : QED

Comment: your first assertion is valid without the absolute value and generally false with the absolute value: $u= e_1+e_2$, $v=e_1$ and $u'= -e_1-e_2$, $v'=e_1$ are not connected by a unitary map.

Comment: I don't see how it follows that the $P_N$ must depend on the scalar product and not some other function of the two states. The scalar product is not the only function of two states that is invariant under unitary transformations, e.g. $<\phi_1|\phi_1> + <\psi_1|\psi_1>$.

Comment: @ValterMoretti Thx for pointing this out, I made the required edits

Comment: @user37222 What this shows is that if two transitions have the same scalar product, then the associated probabilities must be equal : the scalar product $\langle \psi|\phi \rangle$ is enough information to determine  $P_N(|\psi \rangle \to |\phi \rangle)$. Therefore there is a function $f : \mathbb C \to [0,1]$ such that $P_N(|\psi \rangle \to |\phi \rangle) = f(\langle \psi|\phi \rangle)$. If you like more formal mathematics, see the [universal property of the quotient set](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Universal_Property_of_Quotient_Set)

Comment: @user37222  Consider the set $Q$ of pairs of vectors $(|\psi\rangle, |\phi\rangle)$. The transition probability is a map $P : Q \to [0,1]$. Define in $Q$ the equivalence relation $(|\psi\rangle, |\phi\rangle)\sim (|\psi'\rangle, |\phi'\rangle)$ iff $\langle \psi|\phi \rangle = \langle \psi'|\phi'\rangle$. As established by SolubleFish, $P$ assumes  a constant value in every equivalence class. Hence $P$ is a function from the quotient space $Q/\sim$ to $[0,1]$. This is the same as saying that it is a function of $\langle\psi|\phi\rangle$ only.

Comment: SolubleFish & Valter Moretti - thanks for the clarifications.

Answer (score 1):

One can show that it must consist of such scalar products with the aid of the [Haar measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haar_measure). (It is also sometimes called "twirling")

Consider a quantity
$$ Q = \phi_a^* A_{a,b} \phi_b , $$
that is invariant under unitary transformations. It implies that
$$ Q = \phi_a^* U_{a,x}^{\dagger} A_{x,y} U_{y,b} \phi_b , $$
for any unitary transformations $U$.

In that case one can apply an integration over all such unitary transformation to the quantity. It produces
$$ Q = \int \phi_a^* U_{a,x}^{\dagger} A_{x,y} U_{y,b} \phi_b\ \text{d}U , $$
where $\text{d}U$ is the Haar measure.  The result of such an integration produces
$$ \int U_{a,x}^{\dagger} U_{y,b}\ \text{d}U = \delta_{a,b} \delta_{x,y} . $$
Hence
$$ Q = \text{tr}\{A\}\ (\phi^* \cdot \phi) . $$
There can also be higher order quantities with two or more pairs, such as
$$ Q = \phi_a^* \phi_c^* A_{a,b,c,d} \phi_b \phi_d . $$
One can also evaluate the integration over the unitary transformations for such cases. In all such cases, the integration would produce contractions between $\phi^*$ and $\phi$ together with contraction between indices of $A$. Therefore, the invariance implies the scalar products.

Comment: To answer the OP's question, I think you would have to prove that any function of two variables in the complex sphere (with the right hypotheses), invariant under (joint) unitary transforms is of the form you assume for $Q$